# PHP Curl returning 0 bytes

Tags: php, curl

I've looked around a few posts on this but can't seem to get my script to work. It downloads all the files and names them correctly but they are all 0 bytes.

Any help welcome!

Comment: You can see `curl_error()` after execute. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Got it, just using curl_error now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue using `file_get_contents()` instead - works perfectly!

Comment: Just to note, depending on your settings, `file_get_contents()` won't be a drop in replace for the cURL library, due to [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) flag.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, that's useful to know :)